Анонимная отправка сообщений через python
Хочу написать консольное приложение на python чтобы кидать текст с устройства на свой ПК. Но нужно это сделать полностью анонимным приложением клиента, чтоб не был виден ip куда пересылается сообщение и шанс перехвата потока был очень низок. Не совсем понимаю как это сделать, пробовал через socket но там анонимностью и не пахнет...

Нужен какой-то промежуточный сервер. Но в любом случае на каком-то этапе можно всю инфу размотать, если захотеть. Ещё один вариант - коннектиться через  VPN (ну это по сути тоже "через промежуточный сервер").

брокер сообщений какой-нибудь.

Ну это я понимаю, но можно пример кода сервера и клиента

можно в интернете посмотреть, что такое брокер сообщений

Если вы рассматриваете перехват потока как возможную угрозу, то реализовать анонимность невозможно. Перехватчик банально посмотрит размеры пакетов: если из точки А вышел пакет и в точку Б пришёл пакет примерно такого же размера, то можно сделать вывод, что А отправил сообщение для Б. Наличие шифрования, впнов и всяких там брокеров не имеет никакого значения. Таким образом можно даже деанонимизировать пользователей Tor (хотя и сложновато, там свои нюансы есть)
